# Tooltip style. Can't bind to datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf

i have one problem with tooltip. 
I want to add templated tooltip to button with some information inside.

Here the button with tooltip, which datacontext bounded to some viewmodel:

```
<fluent:Button DataContext="{Binding NewConnections, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Command="{Binding AddCloudStorageAccount}" Header="Add Account">
                        <fluent:Button.LargeIcon>
                            <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Icons;component/UI/v1/add_account.png" Width="48"/>
                        </fluent:Button.LargeIcon>
                        <fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip DataContext="{Binding UserInput.AddAccountsButtonInfo, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonTooltip}"></ToolTip>
                        </fluent:Button.ToolTip>
                    </fluent:Button>
```

Style:

```
 <Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ButtonTooltip">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border  Background="LightYellow" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Maroon">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtText" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtDescription" Margin="0 10 0 0" Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtHotKeyDescription" Margin="0 10 0 0" Text="{Binding HotKeyDescription}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I set some breakpoints to see if viewmodel is accessed. And it's ok. But properties like Title not accessed at all and i see only empty rectangle without any text

Do someone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved it(set datacontext in border). Maybe someone will be interested in:

```
<Style TargetType="ToolTip" x:Key="ButtonTooltip">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border  Background="LightYellow" BorderThickness="0.5" BorderBrush="Maroon" DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtText" Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtDescription" Margin="0 10 0 0" Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="_txtHotKeyDescription" Margin="0 10 0 0" Text="{Binding HotKeyDescription}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Would adding a TargetType do the DataTemplate help ? It doesn't feel right to put bindings in a style, though.